How to visit all reachable nodes between 2 points in topological order, visiting each edge once?
I have a directed (potentially cyclic) graph. Some nodes are inputs and some nodes are outputs. I want to iterate over all the edges that form paths between an input and an output. I want to ignore edges that lead to dead end (not to an output) or come from some node that is not descendant from an input.
For example, the follwing graph
0-->4
5-->4
4-->8
7-->6
4-->6
6-->5
1-->5
5-->3
4-->2


Nodes 0 and 1 are inputs and 2 and 3 are outputs. So the iteration I am looking for should ignore edge 4 -> 8 (8 is a dead end), and should ignore 7 -> 6 (7 is not descendent from an input). The iteration order should be in topological order of strongly connected components. I realise that within each scc, there is no single obvious order. I just want to make sure that 5 -> 3 does not get evaluated before 1 -> 5 for example.
I need to do this milions of times for different graphs so trying to figure out the most performant approach. I am open to using something from petgraph and also open to a custom algorithm.
